# How to make a link that will not be added to browser history

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I want to make a secret URL that will authenticate a user to do something, but which won't be there in the browser history.

e.g. I thought something like this would work

1. Special link, e.g. `https://example.org/page#specialHashGivesAccess` is sent to the right people by email. Email is considered secure enough for this purpose.
2. Javascript running on the page sends the secret to a server via ajax which checks it and returns a temporary hash instead.
3. Javascript does a `window.location.replace` to the page with the temporary hash.
4. The app then checks the temporary hash and if OK shows the content.
5. the temporary hash expires in a short while, or can be manually expired.
6. The original special link (1) is not in browser history.

Further more, the script that does this work; the app script and the ajax server, are remote. i.e. siteA that generates `example.org/page` has `<script src="https://siteb.com/app.js">` and ajax is done using CORS.

However it does not seem reliable in my testing, I'm finding `specialHashGivesAccess` in my history.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you send the link via E-Mail or is it somewhere present on the website itself?

Comment: by email. So a certain group of people will receive a link to use. We can trust that their email is secure enough for the purposes. Obviously anyone with the first link can get access; that's acceptable. I'd just like to have one long-lived secure link (these people value convenience) but not to have that stashed in browser history which would give the next user of the browser access.

Comment: Have you tried to use [history.deleteUrl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/deleteUrl) ? It's not supported by Safari and Firefox Android though...

Comment: Thanks Hoargarth, I do need something cross browser ideally, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

**It can't be done** (at the time of posting this answer).

While there are many methods for manipulating the *session* history, it is not possible to prevent an entry being created in the *global* history, or to overwrite the first page load request stored there.

Therefore the solution I'm going to go with is along the lines of

> Hi,
>
> To access the service you can use the following link and password:
>
> - https://example.org/myApp
> - password: aabbccddeeff00112233
>
> If nobody else uses your browser you can use the following shortcut link to save you entering the password, however note that this will give access to the service to anyone that has access to your browsing history.
>
> - https://example.org/myApp#aabbccddeeff00112233